# Handling value in dynamic items Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, calculator

I was preparing calculator in jquery. with static HTML there was no problem to display, handle values of buttons but when I wanted to make it dynamic I stuck in place. I cannot get value from buttons and display it.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="result">test</div>
    <input type="button" value="Calc" id="cal"/>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

My Scripts:

```
$(function(){
$("#cal").click(function(){
    $("#content").append(
            "<div id='container'>"+
                "<input disabled='disabled' type='text' id='display' onclick=''>" +
            "<div>" +
                "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='(' id='paramO' onclick=''>" +
                "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value=')' id='paramC' onclick=''>" +
                "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='%' id='modulo' onclick=''>" +
                "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='C' id='clear' onclick=''>" +
            "</div>"+
            "</div>"
});
```

And now I want to display values of buttons in "display field".

```
$(".signbutton").click(function(){ 
    var i = $(this).val();
    $("#display").val($("#display").val() + i)
}
```

I tried also solution like this:

```
$("#container").on("click", $(".signbutton"), function(event){
    var i = $(event.target).val();
    $("#display").val($("#display").val() + i)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function declarations are in trouble with syntax rules. And define `click` event of `.signbutton` after append the controls.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#cal").click(function(){
  $("#content").append(
    "<div id='container'>"+
     "<input disabled='disabled' type='text' id='display' onclick=''>" +
    "<div>" +
     "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='(' id='paramO' onclick=''>" +
     "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value=')' id='paramC' onclick=''>" +
     "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='%' id='modulo' onclick=''>" +
     "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='C' id='clear' onclick=''>" +
    "</div>"+
    "</div>");
  $(".signbutton").click(function(){ 
   var i = $(this).val();
   $("#display").val($("#display").val() + i)
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">test</div>
    <input type="button" value="Calc" id="cal"/>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problems with non-closing parenthesis.

## Look at this code snippet with those fixes

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cal").click(function() {
    $("#content").append(
      "<div id='container'>" +
      "<input disabled='disabled' type='text' id='display' onclick=''>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='(' id='paramO' onclick=''>" +
      "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value=')' id='paramC' onclick=''>" +
      "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='%' id='modulo' onclick=''>" +
      "<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='C' id='clear' onclick=''>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");

    $(".signbutton").click(function() {
      var i = $(this).val();
      $("#display").val($("#display").val() + i)
    });


    /*

    $("#container").on("click", $(".signbutton"), function(event){
        var i = $(event.target).val();
        $("#display").val($("#display").val() + i)
    }*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="result">test</div>
  <input type="button" value="Calc" id="cal" />
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Now is showing the values using your first approach.

Answer (score 0):

As the guys have mentioned before you should fix the syntax but as I understood your problem they didn't really answer this.

First of all I'd recommend wrapping your jQuery code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//code here
});
```

I've came up with this code for you:

```
"<input type='button' class='signbutton' value='(' id='paramO' onclick='$(\"#display\").val($(\"#display\").val() + $(this).attr(\"value\"));'>"
```

This code set's the input's value to be "Current value + the value of the button"

It's a little *busy* since I've done it on the go and might have some typo's but I hope I've helped you.